# angular ui-router reload one of resolves

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm developing a web application based on angular.js ui-router. I have a page where a lot of info is loading (news, products etc.). This info initializes through state resolves.

```
$stateProvider
  .state("cabinet", {
     url: "/cabinet",
     template: "app/views/cabinet/index.html",
     resolve: {
         news: ["NewsService", function (newsSvc) {
             return newsSvc.getList();
         }], 
         user: ["UserProfileService", function (userSvc) {
             return userSvc.me();
          }],
         services: ["ServiceService", function (serviceSvc) {
             return serviceSvc.getList();
         }],
         products: ["ProductService", function (productSvc) {
             return productSvc.getList();
         }],
         templates: ["TemplateService", function (templateSvc) {
             return templateSvc.getList();
         }]
   })
  .state("cabinet.profile", {
     url: "/cabinet/profile",
     template: "app/views/profile/index.html"
  })
 ...
```

Can I reload only of on resolves of state "cabinet" when I move from another page? For example, I come back from "cabinet.profile" to "cabinet" and I want to reload not all resolves, but only "user". Is it possible? Google tells me nothing about this.

`$state.go("cabinet", {}, {reload: true})` - reload all resolves.

Comment: cabinet is the parent state of cabinet.profile. When you navigate to any child state of cabinet these promises are going to resolve every time. This is not possible to resolve only one promise. if you want achieve this, then you will have to resolve state specific promises.

Comment: @MohanSingh Could you explain, please, what do you mean under resolve state specific promises? I have to create own state for each resolve? If so then how it could be applied to my app? If I want to have one page with several resolves.